# Nested switch alternative

Tags: c++, tree, switch-statement

While playing with NLP I've been encountered with little problem:

```
switch(var1)
{
case Variant1_1:
    if( cond1 )
    {
        if( cond2 )
        {
            if( cond3 )
            {
                switch(var2)
                {
                case Variant2_1:
                    return someExpression;
                // another five-six cases
                default:
                    return;
                }
            }
            else // cond3
            {
                switch(var2)
                {
                case Variant2_1:
                    return someExpression;
                // another five-six cases
                default:
                    return;
                }
            } 
        }
        else // cond2
        {
            if( cond3 )
            {
                switch(var2)
                {
                case Variant2_1:
                    return someExpression;
                // another five-six cases
                default:
                    return;
                }
            }
            else // cond3
            {
                switch(var2)
                {
                case Variant2_1:
                    return someExpression;
                // another five-six cases
                default:
                    return;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    else // cond1
    {
        // same thing

    }
    break;
case Variant1_2:
    // same gigantic tree
    break;
case Variant1_3:
    // here too
    break;
default:
    return;
}
```

What alternatives are for such "computational tree"? The only thing that comes to my mind - some tree container with function pointers as leaves and a great deal of little functions.

Comment: This code should be refactored heavily, not only in this function, but other functions as well. Sometime, refactoring just one function doesn't help much, or it is not that easy, but thinking of the design of the whole project (or at least other related functions), helps a lot.Then refactoring is easy, and you can expect better overall design.

Comment: Are the expressions really independent for every combination of conditions?  In my experience that is rare.  Typically there is some commonality that can be factored out to reduce the number of individual cases to try.

Comment: Considering that this is NLP.. i guess there would be even more :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(tongue in cheek) Every time you encounter a `switch` statement in a C++ program, you know that you've missed an inheritance opportunity.

The two ways I know to refactor multiple parallel switches are (1) building a multi-dimension array of function pointers, and (2) using a variation of the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: O'kay, I guess I'll just stop on multi-array, thanks!
But could you please clarify your vision of "visitor pattern" use in this situation for little unexperienced programmer?

Answer (score 1):

A nice workaround is using a matrix.

This will work well if you know that all the conditions will be evaluated anyway.

Make a multi-dimensional array that will map the true-false values to the handling functions.

```
Arrayswitch[var1][cond1][cond2][cond3][var2]();
```

Answer (score 1):

I start looking for a data-driven approach when code starts to look like this.  It may be as simple as a table or perhaps a tree with function pointers as you've suggested.

If this is a hand-rolled parser of some sort, you might want to look into some references on parsing for ideas on how to use a grammar definition to do the parsing (either by interpretting the grammar on demand, or by using a code-generation tool that uses the grammar as input).

I often hand-roll recursive descent parsers.  Typically, I create a class that holds the state, expose one public "Parse" function, and implement each rule as a private member function.  These member functions are small and explicitly named, so the code becomes quite readable.  It's also very easy to write tests for it.

Comment: It's not just this case, this function dealing with flexes, but thanks for idea! Guess I'll use it soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism and good code design.
http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/polymorphism/intro/

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is what the compiler will make out of your code anyway :) So you're essentially proposing a nested programming language, which brings about Greenspun's law: "Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of Common Lisp."

There are ways of writing this code better to express your conditions. when you have a lot of nested `if() { if () { if() } } }`s, usually just writing `if (!condition) break;` or other escaping method, simplifies the code. not always but a lot of times.